# Measure elapsed time for execution of code

Tags: vb.net, elapsedtime

I need a program that calculates how long it takes to determine whether a number is a prime.

I have tried to measure that time, but the function does not seem to produce the time taken.

Here is my code. What do I need to do to fix it?

```
Function primeNumber()
    Dim Start_Time As DateTime
    Dim Stop_Time As DateTime
    Dim Elapsed_Time As TimeSpan
    Start_Time = Now
    Dim Check As Integer
    Check = 1
    Dim num As Long
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number you would like to determine if it is a Prime Number or not")
    num = Long.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
    If (num > 0) Then
        For i = 2 To (num - 1)
            If num Mod i = 0 Then
                Check = 0
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Check = 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine(num & " is not a Prime Number!")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine(num & " is a Prime Number!")
        End If
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Number!")
    End If
    Stop_Time = Now
    Elapsed_Time = Stop_Time.Subtract(Start_Time)
    Return Elapsed_Time.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.000000")
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by function doesn't produce the time taken? Do you mean it produces wrong result or not producing any result?

In your code you measure the time of the function execution (including the time needed for user input enter). If you want to only measure calculation you need to move the following line

```
Start_Time = Now
```

after

```
num = Long.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
```

To see the result use:

```
Dim time = primeNumber()
Console.WriteLine(time)
```

Comment: Like it implies, it does not produce the time taken to give the output, a user enters a number, which then is determined if it is a prime number or not, the elapsed time is how long it has taken to calculate this, however I only get the answer, but no time figure

Comment: Did you added this line?

Dim time = primeNumber()
Console.WriteLine(time)

It would output the time calculation to console?

Comment: it worked, how would I add the phrase, time "seconds taken to obtain result"

Comment: Console.WriteLine("seconds taken to obtain result: {0}", time)

Comment: I mean the time before the phrase, so e.g. 0.585 seconds taken to obtain result